# Moq dbContext if there are entities with jsonb (postgresql)

Tags: .net-core, nunit, moq, dbcontext, jsonb

I try to moq my DbContext like in memory db. I use PostgreSql in my app, so I have entities with jsonb properties. For example:

```
[Table("examples")]
public class Example
{
    /// <summary>
    /// id (autogenerated by DB)
    /// </summary>
    [Column("id", TypeName = "bigserial")]
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    [Column("layout_config", TypeName = "jsonb")]
    [Required]
    public LayoutConfigDto LayoutConfig { get; set; }
}

[Keyless]
public class LayoutConfigDto
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Координата X расположения виджета
    /// </summary>
    public byte X { get; set; }
    
    /// <summary>
    /// Координата Y расположения виджета
    /// </summary>
    public byte Y { get; set; }
}
```

so LayoutConfigDto just a model for JSON, that doesn't need a table. And doesn't need any relation or configuration for table.
Then I create Test class:

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class ExampleServiceTests
    {
        private IExampleService _exampleService;
        
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            DbContextOptions<ExampleDbContext> options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ExampleDbContext>()
                .UseInMemoryDatabase(databaseName: "InMemoryExampleDatabase")
                .Options;
            ExampleDbContext dbContext = new(options);
            new FakeDatabaseDataGenerator().Generate(dbContext);
            
            Mock<ILogger<ExampleService>> mock = new();
            
            _exampleService = new ExampleService(dbContext, mock.Object);
        }

        [Test]
        [TestCase(0)]
        [TestCase(3)]
        public async Task GetExampleTest(long id)
        {
            ExampleModel example = await _exampleService.GetExample(id);
            if (id <= 0)
            {
                Assert.AreEqual(example, null);
                return;
            }
        
            Assert.AreNotEqual(null, example);
        }
    }
```

When I run GetExampleTest it fails on Exceptions like:

```
System.InvalidOperationException : Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 'UserWidgetModel.LayoutConfig' of type 'LayoutConfigDto'. Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

I can't use [NotMapped] attribute on LayoutConfig field, because I need to get it from DB and  with pgsql driver all works and serializes. But with in memory db it fails. How can I change my Test to make it works? Is there any other options to mock db context?

Answer (score 0):

The error it returns is pretty clear; it tells you what you need to do. If you can't use the [NotMapped] attribute, you need to configure a relationship for the fields it needs